# Perl DBI insert and select

Tags: perl, dbi

I want to copy a single record from a table, modify some of the fields in the record and insert into the same table. The table has 90 columns.

Thought of using insert..select in one statement but there are 90 columns and i need to tell the column name in the select query.  How can i do it in a better way  in perldbi.  Pls provide me an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch and cache the column names for your table using the [NAME statement attribute](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.618/DBI.pm#NUM_OF_PARAMS)

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_table where 1=0');
$sth->execute;
my $cols = $sth->{NAME};
```

then use $cols to construct your insert...select using some replacement function to inject your modifications in the select.

```
my %mods_for_column = ( 'foo' => 'foo+10', 'bar' => 'trim(bar)' );
my $inscols = join(',', @$cols);
my $selcols = join(',', 
  map { exists($mods_for_column($_)) ? $mods_for_column($_) : $_ } @$cols
);
my $sql = "insert into my_table ($inscols) select $selcols from my_table where mumble...";
```

Comment: That should be `$mods_for_column{$_}` rather than `mods_for_column($_)`. And there's a nasty bug hidden in there. What if `%mods_for_column` includes `baz => 0`? Better to use `exists` rather than checking for truth.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info .  i want have  foo replaced by 0. 'foo' => '0'.  foo is a numeric field in the table. It's not working when i have zero in the map.

Comment: @davorg: that's what I get for typing code without trying it :( I edited example incorporating your suggestions.

Comment: @Arav: The problem with 'foo' => 0 in the replacement hash is the liberal true/false evaluation in perl and my original use of ||. The new sample uses exists() instead and will let you specify a falsey value for replacement.

Comment: "The new sample uses exists() instead ".  Not able to understand. Could you pls pasted a sample code

Comment: @Arav I edited the answer, just look st the code blocks above these comments.